# Fade-out and fade-in transition not working on ng-hide

Tags: javascript, angularjs, css

I'm developing an application where a button is to be clicked which
then hides or shows a specific element.

I'm achieving this with ng-hide from AngularJS. For some reason the transition isn't working correctly. I'm quite new to transitions with CSS3 so what am I doing wrong?

All I wish for it to do is a smooth fade in fade out effect so the appearance doesn't seem so un-natural

**CSS3**

```
#custom-url{
    -webkit-transition: all 2s ease;      
     transition: all 2s ease;
}
#custom-url .ng-hide{
    opacity: 0;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<input ng-model="custom_url" id="custom-url" ng-show="customMode" type="text" placeholder="Place your custom URL text here" class="ng-hide form-control"/>
<button class="btn btn-success" ng-click="customMode = !customMode">Make my own URL <b class="glyphicon glyphicon-heart"></b></button></div>
```

**AngularJS**

```
(function(angular) {
    angular.module('urlShortener', [])
        .controller('shortenerController', function($scope){
            $scope.customMode = false;
        })
})(window.angular);
```

[*Plunker*](http://plnkr.co/edit/fNU1Q8evK2QiGBQgL8nF?p=preview)

Can anyone help ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have couple of issues here.

1) When you use ng-show/ng-hide it applies class `.ng-hide` on the element which sets the `display` property to `none` and that is a property which *cannot be animated* hence your opacity rule does not get apply. In order to use the animation with `ng-show/ng-hide` you need to use [`ng-animate`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngAnimate) which *defers* setting the property by adding some intermediate classes in order for animation to complete. Here is a [nice tutorial](http://www.nganimate.org/) also [this one](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/animations).

2) `ng-hide` is applied on the element itself not on its descendant, hence your rule `#custom-url .ng-hide` will have no effect. It should actually be `#custom-url.ng-hide` instead.

3) If you do not wish to use `angular-animate` library then you would need to use `ng-class` instead.

**[Example with ng-animate](http://plnkr.co/edit/40QS6d?p=preview)**

Comment: Great well-documented answer. Thank you